# Force next word to a new line if the word is too long for the textview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have a `TextView`, that when filled programmatically will not properly line break on words.

#### Current Output:

This is what's happening:

```
| Hi I am an examp |
| le of a string t |
| hat is not break |
| ing correctly on |
| words            |
```

#### Expected Output:

I want this:

```
| Hi I am an       |
| example of a     |
| string that is   |
| breaking         |
| correctly on     |
| words            |
```

#### Java:

```
String mQuestion = "Hi I am an example of a string that is breaking correctly on words";
mTextView.setText(mQuestion);
```

#### XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/questionContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionHeaderTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/header_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/category_hint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".05" />

        <!-- THIS ONE WILL NOT WRAP !-->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/questionHolderTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/question_holder"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".05" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answerContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="@string/next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set multiline true and also set the width of the textview

Comment: @MeenalSharma set multi line true? I dont think thats a valid xml command, if it is I couldnt find it

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: Please clean up your comments, as the question has been resolved and these comments are no longer useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can get the text paint using [`TextView.getPaint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getPaint()), then each time you add a new word(Hi, I, am, etc), call `measureText` on the paint. If the result length is longer than the available width of your TextView, add a `\n` before the new word.Reset the data and repeat the steps.

Comment: Ok, if you find a better solution let me know please.

Comment: There is no better solution. Sorry I doubted you, ;)

Answer (score 9):

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

Add this in your Textview. It worked for me!

Comment: starting from android sdk 23

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
private void initView() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        float width = paint.measureText(mQuestion);
        int maxLength = 300; // put whatever length you need here
        if (width > maxLength) {
            List<String> arrayList = null;
            String[] array = (mQuestion.split("\\s"));
            arrayList = Arrays.asList(array);
            int seventyPercent = (int) (Math.round(arrayList.size() * 0.70)); // play with this if needed
            String linebreak = arrayList.get(seventyPercent) + "\n";
            arrayList.set(seventyPercent, linebreak);
            mQuestion = TextUtils.join(" ", arrayList);
            mQuestion.replace(",", " ");
        }
        mQuestionHolderTextView.setText(mQuestion);
    }
```

I measure the string, turn it into a List, then split it at 70% and make a new line. Then I turn the List back into a String and remove the commas. As long as the word is no more than 30% of the remaining line you're in the clear, otherwise adjust accordingly.

It's quick and dirty, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using following method you can get the wrapped text.

As I don't have android set up, so I have written a Test class and called the method from main.  You need to pass textview width. I passed 14 here.

```
    public class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wrappedText=wrapText(14);
        System.out.println(wrappedText);
    }

    public static String wrapText(int textviewWidth) {

        String mQuestion = "Hi I am an example of a string that is breaking correctly on words";


        String temp = "";
        String sentence = "";

        String[] array = mQuestion.split(" "); // split by space

        for (String word : array) {

            if ((temp.length() + word.length()) < textviewWidth) {  // create a temp variable and check if length with new word exceeds textview width.

                temp += " "+word;

            } else {
                sentence += temp+"\n"; // add new line character
                temp = word;
            }

        }

        return (sentence.replaceFirst(" ", "")+temp);

    }

}
```

Output -

```
Hi I am an
example of a
string that is
breaking
correctly on
words
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to suitianshi, below is my solution.

```
 private String getWidthFitString(String input) {
    Paint paint = text.getPaint();
    // you can define max width by yourself
    int maxWidth = getContentMaxWidth(); 
    float width = paint.measureText(input);
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s"));
        int breakLinePosition = 0;
        String toBreakLineText;
        List<String> toBreakLineWords = new ArrayList<>();
        while (breakLinePosition < words.size()) {
            toBreakLineWords.add(words.get(breakLinePosition));
            toBreakLineText = TextUtils.join(" ", toBreakLineWords);
            float currentWidth = paint.measureText(toBreakLineText);
            if (currentWidth > maxWidth) {
                break;
            }
            breakLinePosition ++;
        }
        if (breakLinePosition > 1) {
            toBreakLineWords.remove(toBreakLineWords.size() - 1);
            toBreakLineText = TextUtils.join(" ", toBreakLineWords);
            List<String> fromBreakLineWords = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = breakLinePosition; i < words.size(); i++) {
                fromBreakLineWords.add(words.get(i));
            }
            return toBreakLineText + "\n" + getWidthFitString(TextUtils.join(" ", fromBreakLineWords));
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

It worked and clean code.

Comment: This is working like a charm!! However, I want to add a gap between two line breaks. I tried to put "\n\n" but it isn't working. Would love it if you can provide some changes in the above code for the same!!

Answer (score -1):

TextView is not support in android.Try using

value.replaceAll("\s", " ");

or

htmlText.replace("\n","
").replace("\s", " ")

Comment: Can an admin delete this answer? It's simply embarrassing.