# TextView breaks my word by letters

Tags: java, android, textview

My requirements: create "incoming bubble" with width by content and max width 90%.

I have this markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    tools:background="@color/white_smoke">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flBubble"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_in"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@string/default_content_description"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/primary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="I would like to go to an Italian restaurant"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sometimes I get the following result:
[image: bad word wrapping]

But I expect the following result (it's falsely encouraging screenshot from Android Studio preview):
[image: expected word wrapping]

How can I prevent breaking word `restaraunt` by letters?

### UPDATE

Although I use minSdk=15 I tried to use `breakStrategy` and I haven't get expected result.
`android:breakStrategy="simple"`:
[image: simple break strategy]

`android:breakStrategy="balanced"`:
[image: balanced break strategy]

I found a related question: [Force next word to a new line if the word is too long for the textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636827/force-next-word-to-a-new-line-if-the-word-is-too-long-for-the-textview), but I didn't undestand how can I get maximum available width for TextView with `layout_width="wrap_content`?

It would be great if I could override the `TextView.setText` and place line breaks there if needed.

Comment: check my answer update.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636827/force-next-word-to-a-new-line-if-the-word-is-too-long-for-the-textview) answer will be useful for you

Comment: @AndrewZ I wrote about this answer in UPDATE

Comment: Have you tried `android:hyphenationFrequency="none"` property? and look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851659/how-to-wrap-text-in-textview-in-android

Comment: @KrupaKakkad yes I did, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Did you tried my answer last update?

Comment: Are you using spaces or &nbsp;? can youshow the code that gets/set the text?

Comment: @Dem0n13 check update3 , also changed your textview width to "match_parent"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG, there were `&nbsp;` in my string!

```
value.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Or you can have unbreakable space insteade of simple space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `webview` to achieve this behavior. 
In webview you can use css to adjust text.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209617/2979171)

---

**Update**

You can calculate width of string and add `\n` to string where is string needs to split

```
Rect bounds = new Rect(); 
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint(); 
 textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds); 
 int height = bounds.height(); 
int width = bounds.width();
```

Results is in pixels,  so just check width of your `view` or screen and split the string.

---

**UPDAE2: Example Code**

I just wrote an example with simple layout in activity `onCreate` you can implement it in adapter or whatever works for you.

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt); //textview with empty text
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();

    String text = "some long text here.....";// text data to work on
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int textWidth = bounds.width();// get text width in pixel
    int marginPadding = 100;// we have some padding and margin from xml layouts
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int rootWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels-marginPadding;// maximum width on screan

    if (textWidth > rootWidth) { // check if need to split the string.
        int lineMax = (text.length() * rootWidth) / textWidth; // maximum Characters for each line
        String result = text.replaceAll("(.{" + String.valueOf(lineMax) + "})", "$1\n"); // regex to replace each group(lineMax) of Chars with group of char + new line
        textView.setText(result);
    } else
        textView.setText(text);
```

---

**UPDATE#3: Fixed code for Listview**

**onCreate**

```
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add("000");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeee");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffffffffff");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffffffffff gggggggggggggggg");
    data.add("aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffffffffff gggggggggggggggg hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(data,this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> data;


public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return data.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    final TextView tv_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
    if (data.get(i) != null) {
        tv_text.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //TextView is Ready to be used.
                fixText(data.get(i),tv_text);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}

    private void fixText(String text, TextView textView) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int textWidth = bounds.width();// get text width in pixel
    int marginPadding = 100;// we have some padding and margin from xml layouts
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((MainActivity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int rootWidth =  textView.getWidth();//displayMetrics.widthPixels - marginPadding;// maximum width on screan

    if (textWidth > rootWidth) { // check if need to split the string.
        //int lineMax = (text.length() * rootWidth) / textWidth; // maximum Characters for each line
        //String result = text.replaceAll("(.{" + String.valueOf(lineMax-5) + "})", "$1\n"); // regex to replace each group(lineMax) of Chars with group of char + new line
        String result = wrapText(rootWidth,text);
        textView.setText(result);
    } else
        textView.setText(text);



}

private String wrapText(int textviewWidth,String mQuestion) {
    String temp = "";
    String sentence = "";
    String[] array = mQuestion.split(" "); // split by space
    for (String word : array) {
        if ((temp.length() + word.length()) < textviewWidth) {  // create a temp variable and check if length with new word exceeds textview width.
            temp += " "+word;
        } else {
            sentence += temp+"\n"; // add new line character
            temp = word;
        }
    }
    return (sentence.replaceFirst(" ", "")+temp);
}
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1.0"
tools:background="@color/colorAccent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/flBubble"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:contentDescription="default_content_description"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="I would like to go to an Italian restaurant jkjk l;'"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Result in device]

Comment: It seems too heavy for ListView item

Comment: I used WebView in my project and it wasn't fast even when he was alone, not to mention a ListView with WebView-items..

Comment: I have to compare this `width` with max available width for TextView. How can I do it, if TextView.width == "wrap_content"?

Comment: You can get screen width and if any margin / padding on parent of textview minus them and you have the textview width

Comment: I have a complex layout with many widgets and TextView is inside them. All of widgets are set `width="wrap_content"` or `width="match_parent"`, have own padding and margins. I don't know how can I get the exact `rootWidth`, that equals maximum available width for my TextView.
I asked another question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858874/get-available-width-for-textview-with-layout-width-wrap-content

Comment: @Dem0n13 show us the layout we will figure it out for you

Comment: Layout is already in the first topic. I have a vertical ListView with items of this layout

Comment: @Dem0n13 just edited there was a bit problem I added "lineMax - 8" in last lines . the division is not precisely duo to the characters are different so in case of some characters goes out of the line (around 5 chars some times) we limit "linemax" which is maximum chars per line with a number above 5 that why I minus 8 the "maxline".

Comment: @Dem0n13 I just realized I was doing the opposite of what you wanted to accomplish I think I read it fast! :)  anyway I fixed it added function to wrap the text . so here you have the limited and wrapped text.

Comment: Thank you for perseverance. All ok except `width="match_parent"`. The most difficult part for me is to get your "`rootWidth`" for `width="wrap_content"` as I wanted.

Comment: @Dem0n13 as yo can see im getview of adapter i posted a runable for textview. It will wait until view will used on screen and after that getwidth will not return 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use **MaxWidth** property for textview or else you should provide **width** for textview

```
   <com.custom.views.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_send_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_chat_sender"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:font_name="@string/font_roboto_regular" />
```

Comment: try custom text view with span able set text

Comment: @Keerthivasan Can you give an example for spanable text?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="I would like to go to an Italian restaurant"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This option does not suit my requirements "...with width by content"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 
**Autosizing TextViews**

The Support Library 26.0 provides full support to the autosizing TextView feature on devices running Android versions prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26). The library provides support to Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher. The android.support.v4.widget package contains the TextViewCompat class to access features in a backward-compatible fashion

For Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

For more details Guidelines go [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html#setting-textview-autosize)

Their is Library too [HERE](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

Comment: this feature doesn't solve my problem with breaking letters

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private String getWidthFitString(String input) {
    Paint paint = text.getPaint();
    // you can define max width by your self
    int maxWidth = getContentMaxWidth();
    float width = paint.measureText(input);
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s"));
        int breakLinePosition = 0;
        String toBreakLineText;
        List<String> toBreakLineWords = new ArrayList<>();
        while (breakLinePosition < words.size()) {
            toBreakLineWords.add(words.get(breakLinePosition));
            toBreakLineText = TextUtils.join(" ", toBreakLineWords);
            float currentWidth = paint.measureText(toBreakLineText);
            if (currentWidth > maxWidth) {
                break;
            }
            breakLinePosition ++;
        }
        if (breakLinePosition > 1) {
            toBreakLineWords.remove(toBreakLineWords.size() - 1);
            toBreakLineText = TextUtils.join(" ", toBreakLineWords);
            List<String> fromBreakLineWords = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = breakLinePosition; i < words.size(); i++) {
                fromBreakLineWords.add(words.get(i));
            }
            return toBreakLineText + "\n" + getWidthFitString(TextUtils.join(" ", fromBreakLineWords));
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those whose string has non-breaking space character may try the following:

```
value.replace("\u00A0", " ")
```

Hope this might help

Answer (score -1):

Change your TextView to EditText and put this 2 lines. it should help you

```
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:enabled="false"
```

This will place you text properly and later on you can give a edit feature in your application if you need.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem. There is screenshot: http://imgur.com/rNVvZYr