# Get available width for TextView with layout_width="wrap_content"

Tags: java, android, textview, width

I have a complex layout that has TextView with `layout_width="wrap_content"`. I want to get maximum width that this TextView can fill.

Is there a universal way to do it? Or should I go over all parents and calculate their margins, paddings, etc? How does Android do it?

Comment: XY problem? Why do you need the maximum possible width? How about android:maxWidth?

Comment: I need the maximum possible width to calculate manually do text fit in one line or not and change this text according to this. I don't use maxWidth.

Comment: It's probably better to calculate the text size runtime and adjust until it fits

Comment: I would like to change text value according to maximum available width

Comment: In the TextView's onMeasure(), constraints on the width and height will be passed down from the parent through MeasureSpecs. In particular, they can be UNSPECIFIED, AT_MOST or EXACTLY. In the last two cases, you have your max width. In the first, I don't think you can calculate the max width, but you can take a look at the code of TextView to see what it does in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it's parent and calculate it's width like this. This width would be the maximum width the `TextView` can take provided the parent has no padding.

```
View parent = (View) textView.getParent();
int width = parent.getWidth();
```

If the parent has some padding you'll need to compute it separately and subtract from this width.

```
int paddingE = parent.getPaddingEnd();
int paddingS = parent.getPaddingStart();
int totalWidth = width - (paddingE + paddingS);
```

Comment: Is it correct for parents with `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `layout_width="match_parent"`? I need more universal way.

Comment: What do you mean by *more universal way*? This **will** give you the maximum width the `textView` can take in it's parent irrespective of width parameters of the parent.

Comment: ok, I try to explain. Parent LinearLayout have `layout_width="wrap_content"`, so parent.getWidth() returns zero, if it wasn't rendered, or width of inner children, but not maximum available space.