# Implementing breakStrategy when targeting before API 23

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am using a typewriter effect in a custom `TypeWriter` class that extends `TextView` for an rpg game I'm developing for android. It works well, but I've noticed there's often a 'popping' effect whenever the text goes to a new line, such that a word will be broken into two syllables by a hyphen before reverting a full word a moment later. For example:

```
Today I am
going to the store
```

will briefly change to

```
Today I am go-
ing to the store
to buy milk
```

before popping back to

```
Today I am
going to the store
to buy milk
```

It does this every time the text goes to a new line, which is very distracting and annoying. It also tends to do this for only a single word per text text block, and repeats the same full word --> hyphenated word --> full word process every line.

I've found that using `android:breakStrategy="simple"` in the xml `TextView` fixes this problem perfectly, but it only works for API 23 and up, and right now I'm trying to use a minimum API of 19.

My Question: Is there any way to implement `android:breakStrategy="simple"` for API < 23, or are there any code strategies to prevent a `TextView` from word breaking/adding hyphens? Tbh, I don't even care about the hyphens -- it's that the word breaks, then reverts back to a full word every line that I want to ultimately prevent from happening.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720678/textview-breaks-my-word-by-letters .. please see if this helps

Answer (score -2):

Try your app in Api < 23, There is no this parameter. So it works like

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

Comment: breakStrategy is not available before api 23, this answer doesn't take that into account which is the main point of the question.